# why am I getting an error when calling my image asset in variable? It says "FlutterError (Unable to load asset:)"

Tags: flutter

I'm calling `Image.asset()` then calling the variable that holds the path in my asset folder. Here's my code, this one right here is assigning the path into the imagePath variable. I'm printing it in console and the variable is correct

```
  Future getName(String publisherUid) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(publisherUid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        publisherSchool = value.get('school');
        publisherFirstName = value.get('first-name');
        publisherLastName = value.get('last-name');
        publisherFullName = publisherFirstName + ' ' + publisherLastName;
        publisherUserIcon = value.get('userIcon');
        imagePath = 'assets/images/$publisherUserIcon';
        //print('$imagePath');
      });
    });
  }
```

then right here displaying it in list tile

```
                child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset(imagePath),
                    title: Text(publisherFullName,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
```

then it has an error saying "FlutterError (Unable to load asset:)".
I tried displaying the variable into text like this `Text(imagePath)` and it displays correctly see the image for reference [image]

then i'm trying to display the asset manually like this

```
                    child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset('assets/images/001-panda.png'),
                    title: Text(publisherFullName,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
```

and i'm not getting any error here's the output when you write the imagepath manually [image]

and btw here's my code in pubspec.yaml. it has proper indention because i won't be able to call the path manually if the asset in pubspec.yaml is wrong

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have and asset called exactly like the name you're printing in your Text.

Check into de folder "assets/images/" for that names. Check for empty white spaces or something like that.

Comment: no whitespaces or anything because i tried writing the path manually and it's correct so I guess it does not have anything to do with pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

1. did you properly set up, `pubspec.yaml`, and `image name should exactly match`.
2. you should pass `image path` as string,
   as below

   ```
                Column(  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset(imagePath.toString()),
                    title: Text(publisherFullName,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
   ```

Comment: i tried the `to.String()` but it have the same error also tried to call the path manually to check if the assets in pubspec.yaml has any errors but I'm not getting any errors when calling the path manually

Comment: try to rebuild the app ?